# How to parse an inputted string to extract individual numbers

Tags: python, string, parsing

Going to feel dumb once I figure this out.

The program I'm writing prompts for an operation (e.g. 9+3) and then prints the result.

Example run:

```
>>>Enter an operation: 9+3
>>>Result: 12
```

I'll have four separate functions for the operators +,-,*,/ and another function to receive the user input and print the result after the appropriate function return.

This is my code so far (I'm including only one operator function):

```
def add(n, y):
    result = ""
    result = n + y
    return result

def main():
    op = input("Enter an operation: ")
    for i in range(1,len(op)):
        n = n[0]
        y = y[2]
        if (i == "+"):
            result = add(n, y)
    print("Result: ", result)
    print("Bye")
```

My error in the shell states n and y are not assigned so I'm not parsing them from the input correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are not assigned in the body of the function and not available in the global scope:

```
def main():
    op = input("Enter an operation: ")
    for i in range(1,len(op)):
        n = n[0]  # no n here yet so n[0] won't work
        y = y[2]  # no y here yet so y[2] won't work
```

I think you aim to parse the input, and then use those values to perform addition, something like that:

```
def main():
    op = input("Enter an operation: ")
    i = op[1]
    n = int(op[0])
    y = int(op[2])

    if i == "+":
        result = add(n, y)
    print("Result: ", result)
    print("Bye")
```

But it will work only for one digit arguments, so you might think about some proper parsing using regex, but that's for another question.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. And yes you're right about using regex, that will probably come after these basics.

Comment: Why did you import re and not use it??

Comment: It was a leftover, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your code:

In `main`, at `n = n[0]`, you don't have any `n` defined. So you will get an error. Same for `y = y[2]`.
In `add` you are adding strings. So you will get `'93'` as the answer.

For the proper parsing use regex
Or if you want quick to work, less coding version (not recommended if you are learning)
Try this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        # just a variable used to check for errors.
        not_ok = False

        inp = input("Enter an operation: ")
        inp = inp.replace('\t',' ')

        for char in inp:
            if char not in '\n1234567890/\\+-*().': # for eval, check if the 
                print 'invalid input'
                not_ok = True # there is a problem
                break
        if not_ok: # the problem is caught
            continue # Go back to start

        # the eval
        try:
            print 'Result: {}'.format(eval(inp)) # prints output for correct input.
        except Exception:
            print 'invalid input'
        else:
            break # end loop
```

Some regex links: [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) [2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: `except Exception: print 'invalid input'` might be a bad idea when some unexpected exception is raised since it doesn't necessarily mean that input is wrong. So I wouldn't recommend this code to someone who's learning.